# InvalidOperationException. Cannot bind complex type. Asp.net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to pass `ICallbackSuccess` to Razor Page's `OnGet`

`public async Task OnGetAsync(string phoneNumber, string? returnUrl, ISuccessCallback callback)`

This is interface:

```
public interface ISuccessCallback
{
    Task CallAsync(AppUser user, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager);
}
```

These are implementations:

```
public class SaveAccountChangesCallback : ISuccessCallback
{
    public async Task CallAsync(AppUser user, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
    {
        await signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
    }
}
```

```
public class SignInCallback : ISuccessCallback
{
    public async Task CallAsync(AppUser user, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
    {
        var result = await signInManager.UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            var error = "";
            var errors = result.Errors.ToList();
            for (var i = 0; i < errors.Count; i++)
            {
                error += $"{i + 1}: {errors[i].Description}\n";
            }

            throw new Exception($"Can't create new user: \n{error}");
        }

        await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
    }
}
```

These are call sites:

```
return RedirectToPage("VerifyCode", new
{
    phoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
    returnUrl = ReturnUrl,
    callback = new SignInCallback()
});
```

```
return RedirectToPage("../VerifyCode", new
{
    phoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
    returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl(),
    callback = new SaveAccountChangesCallback()
});
```

The full text of error message:

```
InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Web.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Logic.VerifyCode.ISuccessCallback'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, give the 'callback' parameter a non-null default value.
```

Comment: You cannot pass `ISuccessCallback` to "VerifyCode",why you need to pass it?If you want to call CallAsync in ISuccessCallback,you can call it in OnGet rather than pass ISuccessCallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have memorized value of `callback` in the property, declaration of which is the problem:

`[BindProperty] public ISuccessCallback Callback { get; private set; }`.
Need to remove private for set and everything is done.